# Auto-regeneration disabled when "rake generate"

Tags: octopress

"rake preview" works fine, but "rake generate" alway can't generate the "_deploy" folder.
any ideas?

```
wizards-sharing:octopress wizard$ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css 
Configuration file: /Users/wizard/Git/octopress/_config.yml
        Source: source
Destination: public
  Generating... 
                done.
Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the deploy folder you need to run `rake deploy`

Open your `Rakefile` to understand what this command does. Scroll down this file to where it says `task: deploy do`

I have written a few Octopress posts. Here is one: http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/. Or go to my search and type Octopress. Or just reply in Stack. Thanks.

Comment: ## Deploying website via Rsyncssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Connection refused        
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem with you, here is what I do:
1. Open the Rakefile, and found keyword "--watch"
2. Change the line "Jekyll build" to "Jekyll build --watch"
3. Save and try to run "rake generate"

Then you check the folder "_deploy", you will see the files has already been generated.